# ¿Como puedo usar multiples conexiones en los modelos de laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Guiandome de [***esta respuesta***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel), intento hacer múltiples conexiones de la siguiente manera:

```
'connections' => [

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sistematpm'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'datos' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sistematpm'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'datos',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

],
```

La conexion la pruebo de la siguiente manera y me sirve perfectamente.

```
$users = DB::connection('datos')->select(...);
```

Todo bien hasta allí, pero mi sistema tiene muchos controladores ya creados, sera un poco tedioso indicar a cada funciona cual conexión hace referencia. ¿Se podría editar solo los modelos para indicar donde se encuentra la tabla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, en la misma respuesta hacen referencia a como manejar una conexión distinta a la predeterminada en un modelo, cambiando el valor de la propiedad $connection:

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

El siguiente ejemplo es de la documentación:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'connection-name';
}
```

En ese orden de ideas el valor de la propiedad lo cambias por 'datos'.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models